# Git - applying commits from one branch onto the other using rebase

Tags: git, rebase

For one of our projects we have to use an external companies code base. Once in a while they update their master, which we then have to integrate into our  repo. However, because they do some weird/unnecessary stuff we've got a couple of commits we need to apply everytime they update their master before we merge it into ours. These commits are part of a release branch (let's call it `release/old`. To get the latest changes and apply those commits, what I have to do is create a new branch from their master (`release/new` for example) and then rebase the commits from release/old to release/new.

I first tried `git rebase release/old` from the new branch, but that obviously didn't work as it took the commits from `release/new` and applied them to `release/old`. When I tried git `rebase -i release/new` from the `release/old branch` (so take the commits from old and apply them to new) it went through all the commits, but when I then went back to the new branch and tried pushing it, it said nothing could be pushed, and in `git log` only the commits coming from master are shown.

All I know is that it's been done using `git rebase` before, but I can't figure out what the right command is.

Comment: use `git rebase --onto`; see [this docs entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description).

Comment: so `their master` + `couple of commits applied from your side` = `release/old`? and "new branch from their master (release/new for example)" means `their master` is identical to `release new`?

Comment: Correct, at the moment `release/new` is identical to their master, what has to happen is the commits from `release/old` to be applied to `release/new` (only ours obviously, which are about 8 commits in total). I'll try `git rebase --onto` when I have time, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: if `release/new` is identical to `their master` (i.e. no extra commits from your side added) and `release/old` is based on their `their master` + `a couple of commits applied from your side` then you do not need to rebase at all. You can just create a copy of `release/old` and name it `release/new`.

Comment: Should have clarified, the master `release/new` is based on is newer than what `release/old` is based on, so `release/new` has changes `release/old` hasn't. Simply copying `release/old` won't be enough I think.

Comment: okay, in this case you will not need `rebase --onto`, see my answer for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your situation:

```
a -- b -- c                 <-- their/master
     \ 
      \
       f -- g               <-- release/old
```

1. `git checkout release/old`
2. create a copy of this branch via `git checkout -b release/new`
3. update the `release/new` branch to latest `their/master` via `git rebase their/master` which results in:

```
a -- b -- c                 <-- their/master
      \    \ 
       \    \
        \    f' -- g'        <-- release/new
         \
          f -- g             <-- release/old
```

Your `release/new` now has `their/master` as base, moreover, it has copies of the "couple of commits" that were included in `release/old` on top of this base.